# passando paramentos para função REACT TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, front-end

```
function handleOpenUpdateTaskModal (valor){
   setIsUpdateTaskModalOpen(true);
   console.log(valor)
}

<img onClick={handleOpenUpdateTaskModal('VALOR')} src={Update} alt="Editar" />
```

**Primeiro erro no valor da função** (Parameter 'valor' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006))

**Segundo erro no onClick** (Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.ts(2322))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiro erro

```
function handleOpenUpdateTaskModal (valor: string)
```

Segundo erro

```
onClick={() => handleOpenUpdateTaskModal('VALOR')}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado !